# c# Run App via Html or URL

Tags: c#

I see often websites which can start a application installed on the clients PC.
How is this been done? Is it a Html page, or only done via a URL?
And is there a way to get this running with my c# application?

Thanks

## Edit

As always I found a solution minutes after creating this post.
[Windows solution](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/71831-application-url-launch-local-application-from-browser/)

Answer (score 0):

a> href="\Server\Downloads\Archive.exe" 
  type="application/octet-stream">Clickfile <\a

give the path like this